# converting the varchar value '39.63' to data type smallint

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to move the data in the first table to the second table with conversion of some data type.

I am using a stored procedure to accomplish this but I keep getting an error.
Here is the error message

```
 Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Load_Dim_Airports, Line 5 
 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '39.63' to data type smallint.
```

See the datatype below that we need to convert to. Longitude and latitude need to be concatenated to form a new column called LatLong.

How do I convert and transfer the data from first table to into second table? Then how would I concatenate and have fewer number of columns in the second table than the first table?

**Edit:**

This is the proc I am using but I get error Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Load_Dim_Airports, Line 5 Conversion failed when converting the `varchar` value '39.63' to data type `smallint`.

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_Load_Dim_Airports] 
 AS 
 BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO [AIRPORTS-DM].dbo.Dim_Airports (AirportId, AirportName, City, Country, Altitude, Latitude, Longitude, TimeZone, LatLong) 
 SELECT * FROM DBO.Src_Airports 
 DECLARE @NegativeNumeric decimal (10,2) 
 DECLARE @Latitude decimal (10,2) 
 SELECT @NegativeNumeric = -1 * CAST (REPLACE(@NegativeNumeric ,'-','') AS DECIMAL (10,2)) 
 SELECT CONVERT(Decimal (10,2), CONVERT(Varchar (50), @Latitude)) 
 END 

 EXEC [dbo].[sp_Load_Dim_Airports]
```

Comment: You can't convert `39.63` to int directly. You first need to decide what to do with the decimal part of the number. do you want to round it, floor it or ceil it? all three are possible.

Comment: It seems that the data type of  longitude,latitude in the first table is varchar. Why smallint not decimal? what format of string concatention you need.

Comment: This is the proc i am using

Comment: Don't do `SELECT *` in an insert - specify the column names. Are you sure the correct columns you're selecting are going into the right columns in your destination table? I bet that's the problem here

Comment: Can you describe the structure of the second table. Is it accepted to modify structure of  longitude,latitude  to be decimal (10,2) for fractions.

Comment: Some keywords, such as varchar, were highlighted. Typos such as "i" were corrected (in this case, changed to I). The first apostrophe was changed from MS Word type apostrophe to the generic apostrophe (char encoding = %27). The fourth line of the query was indented a little too far and was moved to the left to place all lines in alignment.